# Patch body: simultaneous updates / users

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to update a google-drive file only partial?

I have a big file with XML, but users can simultaneous work at the same file. What is the best practice for this? Basically it is the same as a regular Google document where multiple users can work in it at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately partial updates to file content is not currently posible. However this is something we are actively looking into.

At the moment though you can only upload the entire file if there has been a change to it.

Comment: This is disappointing - for files of any significant size this basically makes quick updating impossible!